# how to get response synchronously and request asynchronously?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
outArr = [];

var fetchData = async (str) => {

    var b = await fetch('http://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=' + str);
    var c = await b.json();

    console.log(c)

}

function abc(arr) {

    len = arr.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var str = i + '*' + i;
        fetchData(str);

    }

}


console.log(abc(arr));
```

Can you please tell me how to get response of http request synchronously and hitting the request asynchronously ?

**Expected output**

**[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]**

I tried with `async` with **await** but still I get asynchronously response.

Can we do using `promises` ? how to get response using `synchronously` using promises .

[image]

I am getting this response

Answer (score 2):

You can't make anything asynchronous synchronous - instead, the best way would be to make `abc` `async` and `await` each iteration. (That's if you don't want to make all requests at once - if you're OK making all requests at once, use `Promise.all` instead)

You should also take care not to implicitly create global variables as you're doing with `outArr` and `len`.

Here's how you would do it with `await`:

```js
const fetchData = async (str) => {
  const b = await fetch('https://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=' + str);
  return b.json();
}
async function abc() {
  const output = [];
  for (const i of Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => i + 1)) {
    const str = i + '*' + i;
    const result = await fetchData(str);
    output.push(result);
  }
  return output;
}
abc()
  .then(output => {
    console.log(output);
  });
```

(mathjs has a certificate problem, so you may need to add an exception in your browser for the snippet to work)

Comment: The problem is with the domain itself, not just the URL. If you add a certificate exception, it works. (Try going to the site itself first to add it)

Comment: yes thanks..it work..but `asyn` and `await` block the request can we used `hit all service one time and get response synchronously

Comment: Use `Promise.all` instead, call it on a `map` of the initial array to the Promises

Comment: thanks ..for help .can you give your important 5 min to refector user code using promise.all then after i will proceed I never used promise,all

Comment: Please look up the docs and take a tutorial on promises. `return Promise.all(arr.map(i => fetchData(i + '*' + i)))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the index as first parameter. Call fetchData as follows:

```
fetchData(index, expr);
```

Within fetchData, fill an array with the result of the api call

```
outArr[index] = c;
```

Print the result or outArr!

```js
const  arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const outArr = [];
let count = 0;

const fetchData = async (i, str) => {
  var b = await fetch("https://api.mathjs.org/v4/?expr=" + str);
  var c = await b.json();
  outArr[i] = c;
  count++
  if (count === arr.length) {
    console.log(outArr);
  }
};

function compute(arr) {
  len = arr.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var str = i + "*" + i;
    fetchData(i, str);
  }
}

compute(arr);
```

Comment: can you share the output

Comment: @user944513 Added codepen if you want to play around more - https://codepen.io/vijayst/pen/YvLZdb?editors=0012